# I have an FAA ATPL based on a foreign ATPL, can I convert it to an EASA ATPL?

Tags: faa, easa, pilot-certification

I have an FAA ATPL based on my Foreign ATPL. Am I now able to convert my new FAA ATPL to EASA ATPL? Of course with me doing all the exams etc..

or am I only allowed to convert my original foreign ATPL to EASA?

Comment: When you say convert do you mean you got an FAA ATPL on the basis of your foreign ATPL, or that you took the FAA tests?

Comment: I mean I got an FAA ATPL based on my Foreign ATPL..

Comment: Is your FAA ATP unrestricted, or does it say it's only valid together with your foreign ATP?

Comment: What is the difference between the restricted and unrestricted? I mean i completed the ATPL CTB course and skill test with all the requirements

Comment: Maybe restricted is the wrong word, but in the past I had an FAA private license issued under 61.75 based on a South African one. It had this restriction: "ISSUED ON BASIS OF AND VALID ONLY WHEN ACCOMPANIED BY SOUTH AFRICA PILOT LICENSE NUMBER(S) xxxxxxxxxx.
ALL LIMITATIONS AND RESTRICTIONS ON THE SOUTH AFRICA PILOT LICENSE APPLY" I was wondering if your FAA ATP license has something similar on it. As far as I know an ATP cannot be "based on" anything, it's always valid by itself.

Comment: Ok. I know there are piggy back FAA PPL licenses and there are also stand alone FAA PPL licenses. Both can be achieved by converting a foreign license. Is there the same thing for the ATP conversion? I thought the ATP would be a stand alone license or is it not?        For example I was told by the UK CAA that i could convert a standalone ppl license from FAA TO EASA but not a piggyback. So this is why im asking if a FAA ATP is also a piggyback or not?

Comment: @mizzu what does it say on your FAA ATP certificate? If there limitations they'll be printed on that card. What do they say?

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have an ATPL or a frozen ATPL?

Essentially, EASA requires you to sit all the ATPLs as well as the individual IR exam and your practical flight tests for the CPL, ME and IR. That is conditional on you having completed an "approved course of training" and whether your FAA stuff counts I don't know; I doubt it as it isn't EASA. 
Some stuff (CPL, ME & IR) can be converted depending on experience but from what I understand from a friend, many UK schools are very reluctant to do this at all. I can't speak for other EASA nations.

So essentially, plan on doing your ATPL again.